# Is it ok to call virtual functions through an interface on an object passed across a binary boundary?

Tags: c++, dll, shared-libraries

Given this interface:

```
struct ISomething
{
    virtual void __stdcall DoSomething() = 0;
};
```

Can the application call `DoSomething` on a concrete object returned from a dll or shared object safely, even when the compilation settings are different?

(Assume `__stdcall` is `#define`d to nothing on a non-Visual Studio compiler.)

Comment: No, you cannot ignore the calling convention.

Comment: @HansPassant: Good point. I'll add that to the function signature.

Comment: If "shared object" means non-windows (e.g. linux) you can still have __stdcall there with __attribute__((stdcall)), though it works only for i386.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say 'object' are you, in fact, referring to a *pointer* to object in question? I'm assuming so, since you very-well cannot create an ISomething due to the pure virtual decls.

So if you mean:

```
ISomething* pObj = SomeAPICallToGetAnObject();
pObj->DoSomething();
```

then it will work so long as both caller and implementor agree on the calling convention, packing of structured parameters if there are any, etc. Said-conventions are declaration-based, and are contractually enforced by the implementer+caller. Nasty things happen if you fail to define this as part of the declarative contract.

Is such a thing common in practice? Absolutely. The entire COM-side of all the WIN32 api code I often use is most-assuredly *not* compiled with the same various compilation settings I used on a regular basis. But the contract I get from the header decls ensures I use the proper conventions to make it work. Those declarations are, in fact, ensuring my compilation *agrees* with the requirements to make the call a success.

I *hope* I didn't misunderstand your question.

Comment: Nope, you got it. Thanks. I should have remembered COM does essentially this.